# Illegal characters in path. AccountController.cs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, user-accounts

I'm using ASP.NET MVC default account system and recently when I try to login or register I'm getting this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Illegal characters in path.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in
>   path.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 46:             if (ModelState.IsValid) 
>   Line 47:             {
>   Line 48:                 var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password); 
>   Line 49:       if (user != null) 
>   Line 50:                 {
>
> Source File:
>   c:\Users\u1152923\Desktop\newsWebApplication\newsWebApplication\Controllers\AccountController.cs Line: 48

No changes have been made to the AccountController.cs recently, so I dont understand where the problem has come from.

It's possible a change to web.config could have caused the error. The full web.config is below:

http://pastebin.com/iMviLJGS

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please post your **controller** code?

Comment: Hi @MokshShah here you go http://pastebin.com/BiHTEpwp

Comment: Did you check your connection string in web.config? Maybe something went wrong there...

Comment: That exception seems to be thrown from `UserManager.FindAsync`.

Comment: You could be right @AdrianoRepetti as I have been changing them recently. I can't see anything wrong with them can anyone else?

http://pastebin.com/v3qUfQDj

Comment: Sorry @AdrianoRepetti edited it in http://pastebin.com/v3qUfQDj

Comment: Full web.config if it helps anything - http://pastebin.com/iMviLJGS

Comment: Are you certain that the connection string for NewsContext should not match the one for DefaultContext?  I thought that using `(localDb)` pretty much always meant attaching a file from your data directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix it! The problem infact comes from the IdentityModel.cs
Make sure the below is referencing the correct connection!

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection") 
    {
    }
}
```

Thanks all for your help.